# Relating the Psalms to the Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, tehilim-psalms, commentaries

A lot of the commentaries I come across for individual psalms are preoccupied by their prophetic qualities etc, but I would like momentarily to concentrate on how they present the relationship with G_d.

Is there a volume in English of commentaries on, or of general discussion of the psalms which concentrates on how they relate to the Torah / Pentateuch? A book which will help me understand how the psalms illuminate the Torah? It might be arranged psalm-by-psalm, or perhaps might take a seperate theme for each chapter and discuss how that theme is presented by the psalms, giving appropriate examples

<sup>*(Please **be bold** in editing this question if that helps increase its potential for being answered)*</sup>

Comment: The Art Scroll "Tanach Series" two volume Psalms might be helpful. It provides extensive commentary on Psalms and I am almost certain that it explains the connection between Psalms and G-d and the Torah. Consistent with many Art Scroll publications, the commentary is extensive, often word-by-word. (That's why the Book of Psalms is in two rather large volumes!)

Comment: @JJLL I'm aware of the existence of the Artscroll edition already, thank you, and, if I can't find something more explicitly in the vein I'm thinking of, then I will go for that. My fear is that the attention I attempting to focus at the moment might get swamped by the variety of detail it gives.

Comment: What makes you think that the Psalms specifically relate to the Pentateuch? The commentary of Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch on Psalms is a classic and well worth your attention see http://www.feldheim.com/the-hirsch-psalms.html

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I know the Psalms very well, but purely for themselves, shorn of their context. As I learn more about the Torah, which previously I was sketchy on, I can see things in the psalms that previously I hadn't noticed. I'm just seeking some guidance during that process. Sometimes its nice to notice things for yourself, sometimes its nice to have them pointed out :)